# Center an element in middle on screen for an horizontal scroll list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to have the element clicked being positioned automatically at the center of the screen. The list is having a horizontal scroll with some `overflow-x : scroll` which is hiding what's outside of the div(screen). 
I can't find out what coordinates to pass to `scrollLeft()`.

```
$('#timepicker li').on('click',function(){

    var maxScrollLeft= $("#timepicker").scrollLeft('#timepicker').prop('scrollWidth') - $("#timepicker").width();


$('#timepicker').animate({
     scrollLeft: 
});
});
```

Please see my codepen: [codepen](http://codepen.io/nicc/pen/pJXREz)

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
 $('#timepicker li').on('click',function(){

  var pos=$(this).position().left; //get left position of li
  var currentscroll=$("#timepicker").scrollLeft(); // get current scroll position
  var divwidth=$("#timepicker").width(); //get div width
  pos=(pos+currentscroll)-(divwidth/2); // for center position if you want adjust then change this

  $('#timepicker').animate({
            scrollLeft: pos
  });

});
```

Answer (score 6):

Its a little tricky, but here's the solution.

```
  var left = $(this).offset().left
  var width = $("#timepicker").width();
  var diff = left - width/2
  $("#timepicker").scrollLeft($("#timepicker").scrollLeft()+diff)
```

Basically what i've done is get the present left position of the clicked element and divide it with half of the width of the container. This gives the difference which the scroller has to move in order to take the elment to the middle. Hope you understood the logic.

Here's the codepen attached
http://codepen.io/prajnavantha/pen/eNwWgx

You can copy paste this in the code pen click handler and see it working.

Comment: thk it helps on the logic