# Make element float to center of div when selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a couple of tabs and they have horizontal scroll. I would like them to get centered when I select one.

```
<div class="days">
  <span ng-click="changeTab(1)"  ng-class="{ 'active-tab': activeTab == 1 }">Monday</span>
  <span ng-click="changeTab(2)"  ng-class="{ 'active-tab': activeTab == 2 }">Tuesday</span>
  <span ng-click="changeTab(3)"  ng-class="{ 'active-tab': activeTab == 3 }">Wednesday</span>
  <span ng-click="changeTab(4)"  ng-class="{ 'active-tab': activeTab == 4 }">Thursday</span>
  <span ng-click="changeTab(5)"  ng-class="{ 'active-tab': activeTab == 5 }">Friday</span>
</div>
```

So clicking on one of them, I would like them to slide or whatever (animation is not that important) to center of the page.

Tried something like this:

```
$('.days span').on('click',function(){
  var pos = $(this).position().left; //get left position of li
  var currentscroll = $(".days").scrollLeft(); // get current scroll position
  var divwidth = $(".days").width(); //get div width

  pos = (pos + currentscroll) - (divwidth / 2); // for center position if you want adjust then change this

  $('.days').animate({
    scrollLeft: pos
  });
});
```

From this thread: [Center an element in middle on screen for an horizontal scroll list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115929/center-an-element-in-middle-on-screen-for-an-horizontal-scroll-list)

Comment: Can you add a code example of what you already tried?

Comment: @NilsSchlüter edited

Answer (score 0):

Give each one of your span tags a ID and an onclick event.

```
<span ng-click="changeTab(1)"  ng-class="{ 'active-tab': activeTab == 1 }" 
id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Monday</span>
```

Then this script will move the clicked element to the center of the screen.

```
var x_pos;
var y_pos;
var div;

function myFunction() {
x_pos = window.innerWidth/2;
y_pos = window.innerHeight/2;
div = document.getElementById("demo")

div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.left = x_pos+'px';
div.style.top = y_pos+'px';
```

}

This moves without an animation but could add one using setInterval.

Comment: Hm doesn't seem to work. Do I have to add id to each element, or I can somehow add id's dynamically since there are multiple elements?